# how to put post customized in page

Tags: posts, pages

can someone help me please?
for example  i decide to open web about cooking
one of my pages is about posts of how to cook....
the post is full details,but i wanna put only one picture of it (just like in the picture) after each other in one page
i can doo it manually but i want easier way
i know there are some themes that can help me but this is only one page  of my website.
is there any plugin or what can i do?
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template page for the archive food-archive.php and then query the posts

Learn about custom templates:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Learn about posts queries:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/

the query should pull through permalink, post thumbnail, title, and details (which would possibly your excerpt as per your image)